# How to enable Android Things USB modifier GUI/Window Key -> onKeyDown()

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I've connected an USB keyboard to the Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things.

All is working fine except the modifier key: GUI/Window

Is there a way to activate/enable this key that trigger the onKeyDown() Event?

Because at this time if I pressed the "GUI/Window" modifier key on my PC Keyboard... no onKeyDown() is triggered.

Comment: Is that the key with the Windows icon on it? It may only be added as a meta key in conjunction with another key, like in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#META_ALT_LEFT_ON

Comment: You might see if Android Things maps keys the same way as ordinary AOSP: https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files

Comment: @Chris: Thats what I've tried today, but that is not the reason. Whatever you've pressed, normally you will get an onKeyDown() event, whatever you've entered in the key-layout-files. I've also added keys 0-4096 1:1, then you will get these key numbers after onKeyDown(), but this "Window" Key will never fire an onKeyDown(). So something has to be changed somewhere else in the AndroidThings system files.

Comment: @Nick: yes this is the key, and no thats not the reason. You will press the "Window" alone everytime, thats the function of this key. I thing its a bug. Because there are many bugs in the 0.7 version. If you add a "Button" on the screen... then the "Enter" key is not working anymore ;-)  Horrible. So I had to emulate a "Button" with a "TextView".

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing on a mobile phone? I'm not sure what that key is supposed to map to in AOSP. If you have a specific issue, you can use the Android issue tracker.

Comment: @Nick, tested the USB Keyboard with my Asus Android Tablet with Android 6.0 ... all Keys are working fine, incl. GUI/Window key.  But, where is the difference. I think Google will not fix it asap, but I need it. So, it would be nice if i could change it by myself.

Comment: Ok, I've given up. I've connected the USB Keyboard directly with my own driver with bulk communication. Now all Keys are working.

Comment: Can you state which keyCode is sent to your tablet? Do you see any messages at all on Android Things that relate to not receiving that key? Can you create an issue with the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192720%20status:open